# Add prefix from root in angular.json

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have this code in angular.json:

```
"root": "admin/",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "baseHref": "/admin/",
        "deployUrl": "/admin/",
        "outputPath": "dist/front/admin",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/assets/",
            "ignore": ["**/*.svg"],
            "output": "/assets/"
          }
        ],
...
```

But I have problem to display pictures. This doesn't work:

```
 <img src="/assets/images/test.png">
```

And this works fine:

```
<img src="admin/assets/images/test.png">
```

How can I set "admin/" prefix in angular.json for each asset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Directive` to set prefix to `src` attributes of all `img` tags.

Steps are:

1. Generate `directive` through `cli`:

```
ng generate directive set-img-src-prefix
```

2. Config the newly generated `directive` like:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img' // selects all img tags
})

export class SetImgSrcPrefixDirective {
  constructor(public ref:ElementRef) {
    // change anything you want globally here
  }
}
```

3. And as the last step you have to add this `directive` in `app.module.ts`:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {SetImgSrcPrefixDirective} from './set-img-src-prefix.directive'; // import the directive here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SetImgSrcPrefixDirective // add here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```